# How can I use ffplay from Electron.js app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I've installed `ffplay` in my working folder (in `bin` subfolder) using `ffbinaries` ([ffbinaries downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffbinaries)). My current platform is `linux-64`.

I've use:

`var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    player = spawn('./bin/ffplay', ['http://path_to_video_file']);`

but got an error in terminal stderr:

`./bin/ffplay: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory child process exited with code : 127`

How can I get access from my javascript code to this binary for playing videos or how can I get ready-to-use binary which is a built-in for my Electron app?

...Or how can I get all of ffplay possibilities for playing videos inside Electron app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please put the code you wrote in your comment in your question so people can understand the situation better

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. As for OS I use Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get means that ffplay cannot find libSDL.

First, make sure the library is installed by opening a terminal window and typing:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
```

If it wasn't installed, try to run your program again after it was installed.

If you still have the problem, type the following in your terminal window:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

Try again to run your program. If the problem is now solved, edit the file etc/environment and add the setting there to make it permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"` at the end, exit and save.

Hope it helps.